# Errata for Mark Joshi's Concepts and practice of mathematical finance

Tags: finance-mathematics, books

I am wondering if anyone has a PDF copy of the errata for Mark Joshi's book "Concepts and practice of mathematical finance"? It seems that Mark's website markjoshi.com is not accessible anymore. I will appreciate if you can share a copy of the errata, because there are couple of typos I found in the reading the book.

Comment: Yeah I also notice some typos while reading the book. It would be good if someone can share the errata.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Prof. Joshi is not with us any more.
His [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20170908233414/http://www.markjoshi.com/) is still reachable via timeback machine, but many of the older links are missing.

You can find the errata for *The concepts and practice of Mathematical Finance*, 2nd edition
[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120127075430if_/http://www.markjoshi.com/concepts/errata2pt2.txt).